# Is it possible to combine media queries for same CSS rules?

Tags: css, media-queries

I currently have this chunk of codes.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 990px) {
    .community-info-box {
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0;
        float: none;
        ... : ...
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 630px) {
    .community-info-box {
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0;
        float: none;
        ... : ...
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is something like..

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 990px),
@media screen and (max-width: 630px) {
    .community-info-box {
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0;
        float: none;
        ... : ...
    }
}
```

so I don't have to write the same properties and values again since they are same. Any ideas?

I also searched for *"setting more than 2 breakpoints inside a media query"* but there's no luck.

Comment: You can use `or` in media queries.

Comment: Why not just leave it in the 630px query? Assuming you're doing this mobile first there's no need to declare it again?

Comment: @Barmar thanks, I will try that out!

@AndyHolmes I need those rules for <630 and >768 and <990. So, from `631px` to `767px` should remain unchanged.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't have to add @media again in the second line. This should work:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 990px),
screen and (max-width: 630px) {
    .community-info-box {
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0;
        float: none;
        ... : ...
    }
}
```